# Strange Error In Windows Form Application

Tags: c#

My windows form application works fine for about some time without any problem, but after some time (no specific timings) it just dont let me add any component to the Form and whether i delete a component from the form and than run the application, that component (that i deleted before) still shows up. I make changes into the code and into the Looks of the interface but when i build and run i cannot see any changes.

[this is my original form that i made with different background color and no label in the highlighted area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Y53.jpg)

[But when i run the application the color, screen position is set to default, and a label appears (that i used before but deleted it, still appears)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52YMW.jpg)

[Similarly when i try to add any component][3]

[And when i run after adding it doesnot show, happens same with the coding if i change something it doesnot have any effect on anything, no error is shown regarding to this strange activity.][4]

Comment: Seems like you run different .exe.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint and debug the app does it get hit?

Comment: @Fabio how to correct it then?

Comment: @user1620220 no it isnt hitting

Comment: Check Build section in project properties.

Comment: It is as it is, showing the correct folder in which the code should be built